# How can I bypass connection timeouts while using Pro's field calculator on a hosted feature layer?

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, arcgis-online, error-999999, hosted-feature-layer

I am currently working with a hosted feature layer from an ESRI Solution on AGOL that has a little over 10,000 rows. I currently need to make some attribute updates, however when using field calculator, the tool fails with the following message for any query over 300 rows.

> ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Contact
> Esri Technical Support (http://esriurl.com/support) to Report a Bug,
> and refer to the error help for potential solutions or workarounds.
>
> ERROR: code:502, An error occurred., Proxy or Gateway Server did not
> allow the URL. Check with your LAN administrator that Proxy or Gateway
> server is configured to allow the URL. Failed to execute
> (CalculateField). Failed at Thursday, April 6, 2023 1:18:25 PM
> (Elapsed Time: 25.16 seconds)

It appears there may be a time-out issue occurring with larger sets as opposed to the smaller set, as these errors do not appear to present any relevant information.

I need to come up with a solution that will allow me to use the field calculator function (either from the field calculator or as a standalone script) that will get me passed this. The solution must be in ArcGIS Pro, as the AGOL arcade field calculator cannot be used on this layer.

For reference, my field calculator script is:

```
utilstatus = calc_status(!utilnotes!)
    
def calc_status(utilnotes):
        if utilnotes == 'Installation date serve as verification per Logics records.':
            return 2
        else:
            None
```